# Xcode Instance method not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, instance

sometimes I get the Warning for example :

> Instance method '-PushBottom' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

because the function PushBottom is under this function (where it called) declared.

For fixing this warning I put the function PushBottom about this function (where it called).

Is there any way to get fix this warning without put function PushBottom about the function where it called?

Answer (score 3):

you could declare the push button in the .h file

```
-(void)PushButton;
```

or `-(IBAction)PushButton:(id)sender;`

depending on what the function is.
just declare it in the .h file  above the @end and u should be good to go

Answer (score 2):

I would define it in your .m file (the .h file is your public api file and unless you want it to be public, I wouldnt put it in there as suggested in another answer).

Above the `@implementation` In your .m file write:

```
@interface yourClassName()
-(void)yourMethod;

@end
```